# When does a question check for updates?

Tags: support

I just posted a question on http://electronics.stackexchange.com and kept checking both the inbox and the comments section to see if there were any queries.

Nothing happened for 40 minutes (not even a box saying load more comments) but when I clicked F5 a couple of comments appeared (and messages in the inbox) plus an answer that had been posted 35 minutes earlier.

I am using an up to date Firefox 24.0 and the web page was in the currently selected tab and I occasionally moved the mouse pointer if the screen saver kicked in.

So my question is: when does the question check for updates, and is there anything I can do to make comments/answers automatically appear (or do I just need to keepy hitting refresh)?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a modern browser, then you will be notified of updates pretty much instantly. Check to make sure you do not have JavaScript disabled on the site, either through the settings menu or through a plugin like NoScripts.

Comment: Thanks, Javascript is enabled, and often the notifications do appear without a refresh.  I guess I'll boot up firebug and try to see what is going wrong.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The "NoScripts" warning by Chris is to the point, but not accurate enough. Apart from the obvious: enable stackexchange.com, it's equally important to enable **sstatic.net** in the noscripts plugin.

Comment: +1 Good point, I should have mentioned that too